# Running Maple MPL Scripts

Tags: maple

I have a client who creates scripts in Maple, and wishes to continue to do so. I need to be able to run these scripts on a web server. I am asking here before going direct to maple soft. 
Is is possible to run .mpl scripts without purchasing maple itself? If not is it possible to install maple (single user version) on a Ubuntu server without a GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every installation of Maple comes with a CommandLine Interface (a.k.a. CLI or TTY).

On Linux it runs from any tty terminal, and can be lauched via script.

On Linux it is located as the executable $(MAPLE)/bin/maple where MAPLE say is the installation location.

The CLI has several commandline options. But in order to run a plaintext file of Maple language code you can simply pass the filename when calling the executable. Eg,

```
maple myfile.mpl

maple myfile.mpl > out.txt
```

and so on.  Completely usual Linux/Unix commandline stuff.

Comment: Does the maple installer allow install from the commander line?

Comment: I believe that it does. Read the Installation Guide, which has a section on silent installation and a table explaining all the commandline options for the installer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [Maple Player](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/Mapleplayer/), which is freely available.

Comment: How do I run a .mpl file from the command line? (This is just a file containing maple commands).

Comment: Hm.  On second thought, this is not as promising as I thought.  It seems the Maple Player can't read a .mpl file.